# How to create tooltip directive that will work on any html element with angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

Look at this simple tooltip onMouseOver event:
http://jsfiddle.net/HJf8q/2/

I would like to create a simple tooltip directive in angular 2 that any HTML element that will have that directive, will add dynamicly the innerHTML needed for that tooltip to work.

If I have a simple div:

```
<div id="mySimpleDiv">Hello div</div>
```

Than adding **tooltip** directive should create dynamicly the next innerHTML:

```
 <div id="mySimpleDiv" tooltip>Hello div   
   <!-- the innerHTML should be added -->
    <span id="tooltip-span">
        DO THIS
    </span>
    <!-- the innerHTML should be added -->
</div>
```

now, I understand directive don't have template, they add behavior, but what if the behavior is innerHTML? Should I use another component with the  template? How to approch this?